# Is there a word for using a word twice to imply something different?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for using a word twice to imply something different? eg.

> Are you done, or are you done done?

Comment: As Peter Griffin put it in his racist joke: "White white. Not Mexican white"

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate. If only I could remember what the original one was called… it had some good answers.

Comment: Do you want a single word or a single single word? Just had to ask.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- are you making a very subtle joke?  (There is [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172083/what-is-a-word-called-that-consists-of-a-repetition-of-one-word/).)

Comment: Ask [Dr. Goldberg](http://jezebel.com/5369395/whoopi-on-roman-polanski-it-wasnt-rape-rape).

Comment: @Malvolio No, no joke. I remembered there was another question that was exactly the same as this; but I couldn't remember how that question was phrased, and I couldn't find it. Someone else did, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doubling of a word is known as **reduplication**.

[De Gruyter](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-hpG6PBljIAC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=%22coffee+coffee%22+reduplication&source=bl&ots=RTvG3LS2VK&sig=gew_7T0opZXYw3O0RTDfDXb7d3M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5fjGU-jMM5CV0QXkz4CYAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22coffee%20coffee%22%20reduplication&f=false) says that it is artificial to try to distinguish intensification ('a little, little grave') and attestation to the genuineness / prototypicality of an article ('coffee coffee'; 'the Woman woman' [from 'Sherlock']) so this word covers both cases. A little, little grave is a truly little grave; coffee coffee is the real thing.

Comment: And so would the singling of a word be duplication?

Comment: No, singling a word implies a songl.

Comment: More specifically, *contrastive focus reduplication*.

Comment: Yes. That's the '_coffee_ coffee' usage (contrasting ersatz and the real thing), not the 'little, little' or to show what's happening  'little ... **little**' (reinforcing) usage. So _I do_ think it makes sense to distinguish the two. Though there are probably places ('_grey_ grey') where they're indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

*Doubling* comes to mind.

And it is not limited to individual words, as my first and last examples below show. In addition, the repetition does not *imply* something different, it *states* it, emphatically.

The effect is to mean "really/truly" or "real/true." So the repeated word or phrase emphasis its authenticity.

Real-life examples I've heard:

At a drive through window:
One server: You need the coke right now?
Second server: I need one *right now right now.*  ("right now," "really" right now, immediately, not two minutes from now)

In my parking lot:
Neighbor 1: Are y'all leaving *now or now now?*
Neighbor 2: We're leaving now now. (really and truly now, immediately, not three hours from now, not after we finish packing; we've done all that and we are ready and set to depart--any minute).

Other examples:
We live in the country.
The country or the *country country?*
The country country, the real country, where the cows graze and the stars shine bright, and you'll be lucky to have cellular phone service.

Is she your girl friend or your *girl friend girl friend?* (Is she somewhat of a girl friend (e.g., a female friend) or is she someone who is actually, truly, really, a bona fides girl friend.

Answer (score 0):

"Antanaclasis"

> A figure which consists in repeating the same word in a different
>   sense .

[Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Antanaclasis)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this is not what OP means. An example of antanaclasis is:'If you don't look good, we don't look good.' (Vidal Sassoon)