# What is this way of speaking called?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, literary-techniques, literary-english

I was having a conversation with my friend the other day. At one point, we were talking about a very wealthy individual that has amassed a significant amount of wealth. I told my friend that this person is “loaded”. My friend responded by saying:

> He is not only loaded, he is LOADED.

I often find my friend talking in this way. He likes to repeat the word, however, he strongly emphasizes it and seems like he is intending to make the word more powerful, or something like that?

What is the name for this type of sentence?

Comment: I'd just call it adding emphasis.

Comment: In rhetoric, ***epizeuxis*** is the repetition of a word or phrase in immediate succession, typically within the same sentence, for vehemence or emphasis.

Comment: Sometimes the device is used when the word being used was not quite exact. An extreme example could be "That guy is pretty dead." "No, that guy is DEAD."

Comment: Probably answered at [Is there a word for using a word twice to imply something {perhaps slightly} different?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185482/is-there-a-word-for-using-a-word-twice-to-imply-something-different/185487#185487). 'Reduplication'. 'He is _**loaded**_ loaded.

Comment: Not that different from a "wealthy individual that has amassed a significant amount of wealth."

Comment: [*“Are you hungry or hungry?”](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+hungry+or+hungry+she+asked%22) she asked when he set her down. “I can eat later.” “Good.” Holding him by the sleeve, she took him upstairs.* Perhaps in the actual book, the second instance of ***hungry*** there was orthographically distinct, to provide emphasis. So *"I can eat later"* means the guy was only as hungry as the *first* instance (if his hunger had matched the *second* instance, he'd have had to forgo the preprandial sex on offer upstairs! :)